# For looping and string

Tags: c#, string, loops, for-loop

So I have a string, and in it, I want to replace last 3 chars with a dot. 
 I did *something* but my result is not what I wanted it to be. 
Here is my code:

```
string word = "To je";
        for (int k = word.Length; k > (word.Length) - 3; k--)
        {
            string newWord = word.Replace(word[k - 1], '.');
            Console.WriteLine(newWord);
        }
```

The output I get is: 
To j. 
To .e 
To.je 
 
But the output I want is: 
 To... 
 How do I get there? 
So the program is doing something similar to what I actually want it to do, but not quite. 
 I've really been struggling with this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Err.. do you mean you want to replace the last three characters with dots?

Comment: OK, now what if the original string is only one or two characters? Would you still want to replace them with dots?

Comment: Try something like `string newWord = word.Remove(word.Length - numberOfDots) + new string('.', numberOfDots);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the original word afterwards
Using Jon Skeets method

```
string word = "To je";
word = word.Substring(0,word.Length - 3);
word += "...";

Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. It does not always replace the last 3 characters of a string with dots, it replaces _all_ instances of the last 3 characters with dots. Try `string word = "aaaaa";` - _all_ characters will be replaced by `.`.

Comment: Jon Skeet's answer is not down-voted for the same flaw?

Comment: It should be downvoted too, but at the same time he diiid mention the correct answer at the bottom, so...  I dunno.

Comment: sorry I was just correcting his mistake, I will update my answer

Comment: Please correct the loop condition syntax. One of the commas should be a semi-colon.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
string newWord = word.Replace(word[k - 1], '.');
```

You're always replacing a single character from `word`... but `word` itself doesn't change, so on the next iteration the replacement has "gone".

You could use:

```
word = word.Replace(word[k - 1], '.');
```

(And then move the output to the end, just writing out `word`.)

However, note that this will replace all occurrences of any of the last three characters with a `.`.

The simplest way to fix all of this is to use `Substring` of course, but if you really want to loop, you could use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(word);
for (int k = word.Length; k > (word.Length) - 3; k--)
{
    builder[k - 1] = '.';
}
word = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: The *only* sane way to do it is a substring, the current .Replace way will screw up on strings like "aaaaa".

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva: Agreed. Will edit to point that out. Have also included an approach using `StringBuilder`, if the OP really wants to see looping in action.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're replacing *all instances* of the character at each of those three last positions with a period.  You only want to replace that one character at the end.  "aaaaa" shouldn't become "....." but rather "aa...".
2. You're printing out `newWord` after calculating an intermediate value and then never doing anything with it, leaving `word` unchanged.  You'll want to assign it back to `word`, after correctly adjusting the character in question.

Of course the far easier solution (both for you, and for the computer) is to simply concat a substring of the string you have that excludes the last three characters with three periods.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string is always at least 3 characters, you could substring everything but the last three characters and then append the three dots (periods) to the end of that string.

```
string word    = "To je";
string newWord = word.Substring(0, word.Length - 3); // Grabs everything but the last three chars
newWord       += "..."; // Appends three dots at the end of the new string

Console.WriteLine(newWord);
```

Note: this assumes that the input string word is at least three characters. If you were to supply a shorter string, you would need to supply an extra check on the string's length.

Comment: Should throw in an if check to ensure length > 3 for future cases (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

as [@jon-skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) said, you could do this with substrings.  Here are 3 ways that you could do this with substring.

You could use String.Concat

```
string word = "To je";
word = String.Concat(word.Substring(0,word.Length-3),"...");
Console.WriteLine(word);
```

You could use the + operator

```
string word2 = "To je";
word2 = word2.Substring(0,word.Length-3) + "...";
Console.WriteLine(word2);
```

You could use String.Format

```
string word3 = "To je";
word3 = String.Format("{0}...",word3.Substring(0,word.Length-3));
Console.WriteLine(word3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but all of the other solutions posted so far do not elegantly handle the case that the string is shorter than the requested number of replacements, or an arbitrary number of replacements. Here is a general function for replacing the last *n* characters at the end of a string with a user specified value:

```
static String replace_last_n(String s, int nchars, char replacement='.')
{
    nchars = Math.Min(s.Length, nchars > 0 ? nchars : 0);
    return s.Substring(0, s.Length - nchars) + new String(replacement, nchars);
}

Console.WriteLine(replace_last_n("wow wow wow", 3));
Console.WriteLine(replace_last_n("wow", 3, 'x'));
Console.WriteLine(replace_last_n("", 3));
Console.WriteLine(replace_last_n("w", 3));
Console.WriteLine(replace_last_n("wow", 0));
Console.WriteLine(replace_last_n("wow", -2));
Console.WriteLine(replace_last_n("wow", 33, '-'));
```

Output:

```
wow wow ...
xxx

.
wow
wow
---
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (word.Length > 3)
    Console.WriteLine(word.substring(0, word.Length - 3) + "...");
```

or something along those lines, no need for a loop!